# why mysql "LOAD DATA INFILE" buffers data in memory and very CPU intensive?

Tags: mysql

when we load data from binary tsv file with mysql -e "LOAD DATA INFILE..."
i see memory goes up i think loading the whole file in memory (if it has enough).
and then , we need to wait for the next "memory upload"

is there some sorting going on?
it takes may be a minute to load 4G file into memory.
if i just copy this file to "in memory partition" (tmp fs) it takes few secs
so it must be doing something with data cpu bound

thanks

load binary encoded files to mysql table with "LOAD DATA INFILE"

Comment: Please post TEXT results of A) SHOW CREATE TABLE your-tbl-name;  and B)  SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE name LIKE "your_tbl_name"; after your table creatinon is completed for analysis.